# Does Pantheon support windowshades, popup menus?

Tags: pantheon

Does the Pantheon desktop support:

- 'windowshading' of open windows?
- Popup menus?

I haven't been able to determine this from anything online, and would like to find out without doing a full installation of Elementary.

thanks

Comment: As for window shading, if I remember correctly yes. But, what do you mean by popup menus?

Comment: Some desktops (such as xfce) create (or let you create) a menu that will appear when you left click anywhere on the desktop.  It's an alternative to launching applications from a menu bar or dock.  It's an old mechanism, but the one I like best.

Comment: those are usually called desktop menus.

Comment: there is a plugin for plank (included by default, but hidden) that provides such menu

Answer (score 2):

Pantheon supports Window Shading (to my memory), but not Desktop Menus (what you are calling popup menus).

Slingshot provides that purpose. You however mimic this functionality (almost) by using keyboard shortcut to open Slingshot (`slingshot-launcher`) at any location on the desktop.

Comment: @zeke14 it's the standard application launcher on the Pantheon Desktop (what you get when you click "Applications"). I would provide a screenshot but I am not on elementary at the moment.